# List files on a directory on C

Tags: c, linux

I am starting to learn c and i need a little help understanding this code:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <dirent.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
        DIR             *dp;
        struct dirent   *dirp;

        if (argc != 2)
                err_quit("usage: ls directory_name");

        if ((dp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
                err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);
        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
                printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);

        closedir(dp);
        exit(0);
}
```

So, i know that the first if will tell you that you are missing the directory from which you want to list the files, but i´m totally lost with the next if and the while, which i know that will print the files but i fail to understand the conditions of the while, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the man-pages for [opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

- If condition will open main directory from which you want to read files.It will return NULL if it fails to open it.
- Second , while condition will read files from given directory one by one and printing name of files.
- `readdir` will read first file form directory and and will return NULL if it fails in reading file.
- So in while condition if `readdir` is successfully read file then it will not return NULL.So now condition becomes like `while(dirp != NULL)`.